# What does "Watched" mean on the new summary page?

Tags: support

So the new layout - don't know...

But what does the tag "Watched" mean? And why does one variant have an eye icon? Just curious - couldn't find solid info on this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: However, the "Watched" badge no longer appears. 

Comment: Indeed... I have updated my answer. Let's see how long it takes to become wrong again hahaha

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, Watched means the question has a tag you are watching. In the past, such questions showed up with a faint highlighting effect, which was not particularly informative either. [Some users prefer the old design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375520/322419).

Eye icon - apparently there's a [bug with that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el#comment1250911_375509) that should get fixed soon. It's supposed to be on all of them.

---

**Update**

Apparently, while other elements of the new layout remain, the watched button has been removed in favour of the old way of showing that one was watching one of the post's tags (the orangey highlighting). At least, that's what I've been seeing for the past ~12 hours, and since [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375520#375520) has a status-completed tag, it looks like this particular change has been reverted.

---

**Er... another update**

It has been changed again - now any tags one is watching are appearing  (along with other tags on the question) in a yellowy colour with an eye icon - I like this - much more understandable than the cryptic highlighting or mysterious Watched plaque :)

Comment: Yes the latest iteration of this actually makes sense! 